# How to limit attempts to send an authorization request on react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile-development

I am using React Native. I have an application for a store. I want to add a login limit. A user can try to log in x times and then wait 30 seconds. I have used asyncStorage to store the number of logins and the time of last authorization, however once the app memory is cleared, all data is deleted. I considered using the rn file system, but it can be accessed and bypassed if desired. Because of this, the store may spend extra money as it will send paid sms. What is the right way to implement these restrictions? Are there any standards for authorization restrictions?

I have used asyncStorage to store the number of logins and the time of last authorization, however once the app memory is cleared, all data is deleted.

Comment: You should consider implementing this on the backend. Your api can store records of logins in a database on your server and rate limit based on the user's credentials.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the backend instead of app memory**

Store the number of logins and last authorization info at the backend level. Even if the memory is cleared, the login limit logic would be still in place.

Comment: To store the number of inputs on the backend we need to understand to whom to assign these inputs, in fact before authorization we do not know who is in front of us and made requests to enter one person or several. How to store data in this case? By ip? Or by phone token?

Comment: @Kirill Do you require email or phone number for login? The SMS sending logic is at the backend? If correct, at every request, log the unique identification info (email or phone) and timestamp in a database and check against the record at every login request before sending the SMS.